# Multipart/form-data broken after apiKit router Mule4

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4, apikit

having issues with **reading data from multipart/form-data after the request goes through ApiKit router in Mule4 app**.

There is a RAML in place, used in ApiKit router to validate & route the requests.

```
#%RAML 1.0 
title: ACC race data API
description: API for designing and updating race data
version: 1
protocols: [ HTTPS, HTTP ]

/acc/reverse/entrylist:
  description: Used to manipulate entrylist for ACC reverse grid.
  post:
    description: Creates new entrylist based on supplied quali result, race one result and race one entrylist.
    queryParameters:
      positionsRotated:
        description: Parameter defining how many positions to rotate.
        required: false
        type: number
        example: 30
    body:
      multipart/form-data:
        properties:
          qualifyResult:
                description: File containing qualifying result.
                type: file
                fileTypes: ['application/json']
                required: true
          raceOneResult:
                description: File containing race 1 result.
                type: file
                fileTypes: ['application/json']
                required: true
```

The validation works fine - if the data are sent in incorrect format, the exception is returned. For correctly formated data request is routed to the flow `post:\acc\reverse\entrylist:multipart\form-data:acc-race-data-config`.
Between the steps, payload format is changed (by Mule) from payload in readable form (see below) to `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@379ebdd5`

Readable format of payload data (received to the app) before ApiKit router:

```
----------------------------180928595588258919887097
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qualifyResult"; filename="json1.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "json1": "1"
}

----------------------------180928595588258919887097
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="raceOneResult"; filename="json2.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "json2": "2"
}

----------------------------180928595588258919887097--
```

The following dataweave script works fine if used **before apiKit**, but it doesn't work in the flow called by ApiKit:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.parts[1].content
```

The example of output if above DW is used **before** ApiKit:

```
{
  "json2": "2"
}
```

The example of output if the same DW is used **after** ApiKit:

```
org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "javax.mail.internet.ParseException - Missing start boundary, while reading `payload` as MultiPart.
Trace:
  at main (Unknown)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0

output application/json

---

payload.parts[1].content".
```

Testing in Anypoint Studio 7.8.0, supposed to be used on Mule4-CE runtime once finished and ready to deploy.
Using Postman v8.5.1 for testing. sending form-data body with qualifyResult and raceOneResult parts containing JSON data, default headers, basic auth, query param `positionsRotated=30`.
Url called: `https://localhost:443/api/acc/reverse/entrylist?positionsRotated=30`
Tried to generate multipart/form-data body manually using a RAW type of payload, but the results were the same. Everything works fine if there is no ApiKit.. but I would like to use it to validate request validity.

Thanks to everyone replying for any useful hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested a similar scenario I had with the latest versions and I didn't had that problem. If you are using older versions of the HTTP connector and APIKit module try upgrading to the latest releases. Anypoint Studio has a feature to detect newer releases of connectors: https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.9/update-modules

Comment: I am receiving multipart and trying to read the two files to generate json.

Comment: Sorry. The question wasn't clear to me. What versions of APIKit and HTTP connector is the application using?

Comment: Np, APIKit module version is 1.3.6, HTTP connector version is 1.5.6.

The update of APIKit version to 1.5.1 helped to resolve the issue. Thanks for hte hint!
Please create an answer with this suggestion so I can give you a green check to give you credit.

Comment: Makes sense, my test with latest releases worked. I have updated this answer.